# Does Jenkins swallow MojoFailureException?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I have configured maven surefire plugin with parameter:

```
<configuration>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>60</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
</configuration>
```

So when test's working more then 60 seconds, the surefire plugin interrupts it.

Everything works perfectly on my local machine when I use `mvn test` or `mvn install`, but  when I try to build project on Jenkins it just swallows exception, writes into log `[ERROR] There was a timeout or other error in the fork` and continues the build. As result I get a `Finished: SUCCESS` message.

**Question**: Have anyone got this problem? Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: did you try to run the Jenkins maven build with -X -e flags to get more details?

Comment: -X will show the exception print stack trace  in more details. So use -X option ex:- mvn -X clean etc...

Comment: Yes, sure. '-X' option shows only maven specific thinks, so I've convinced that I use the same versions of Maven (3.3.3) and Java (8u40). With '-e' option I've seen stack trace on my local machine but nothing in Jenkins.

Comment: Maven goals on Jenkins are configured as '-X clean install -e -U'.

Comment: it's a maven build or a freestyle build executing maven?

Comment: in a maven build, Jenkins will run it always using -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true, which turns the build to unstable and maven to success. For a freestyle build running maven you don't have this behavior instead. So try setting -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false and run it again in the former case

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Can you give the information where `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` is defined by default in Jenkins, cause in my Jenkins builds this is only done if i define so and not related to the project type...

Comment: @khmarbaise as per my answer, [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655) jenkins ticket provides the related details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important difference between default options of a maven local build and a Jenkins maven job is that locally the [`maven.test.failure.ignore`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) option of the Maven Surefire Plugin is set to `false` (reasonably) so that test failures will also fail the build.

From [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html):

> Set this to "true" to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.

However, a Maven Jenkins job will always run setting the same option to `true`, as such making the Maven build successful even with test failing and turn the status of the Jenkins job to `UNSTABLE` (and not `SUCCESSFUL` or `FAILED`, which may be a point of debate indeed).

This behavior is also documented in an official Jenkins issue [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655)

> Following the Jenkins Terminology, when (surefire or failsafe) tests fail, the Jenkins build status must be UNSTABLE:
>   << A build is unstable if it was built successfully and one or more publishers report it unstable. For example if the JUnit publisher is configured and a test fails then the build will be marked unstable. >>

So, in a Maven Jenkins job, if a test fails:

- Maven build is `SUCCESSFUL`
- Jenkins build is `UNSTABLE`

Instead, in a freestyle Jenkins job executing Maven, if a test fails:

- Maven build is `FAILED`
- Jenkins build is `FAILED`

Possible solutions:

- Change the build to a freestyle Jenkins job running maven (which may be too much work though) or
- Add the `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false` option to your build (however, you would not have `UNSTABLE` builds any longer).